# how can i read data from db on server to another db on another server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two similar database with the same schema.But one is for printing purpose.
My window form application needs to read data from dby on server1 to dby on server2.The servers are on different network but can communicate. Am trying to use subquery this is
query:

```
Using main_db
Insert into socio_bio 
select * from socio_bio where receiptno in (
)
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: @marc_s, The database system is sqlserver 2008

Comment: Thanks - that should be something you **always** put in your tags to make things clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this stored procedure: sp_addlinkedserver()

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'yourServerName'
select * from [server].[database].[schema].[table]
```

and in your example

```
select * from [yourServerName].[testdb].[dbo].[table]
```

Comment: Delreli, Now understand that i need to create a linkedserver